# Exclude session tracking on specific web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page used for delivering RSS feeds, however it's triggering a session state  (Session_Start) every time a users RSS client sync's with the feed, skewing visitor count tracking numbers. I'm hoping I can use some code to not trigger the session variable when this particular page is opened (albeit via RSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable session state for a particular location using the following entry in web.config:

```
  <location path="MyRssFeedLocation">
    <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="false" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Would: <location path="ListRSS.aspx"> work? or would I need to specify a folder?